# При вставке из буфера обмена VsCode автоматически добавляет точку с запятой и перенос строки

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code, eslint, prettier

При вставке из буфера обмена VsCode автоматически добавляет точку с запятой и перенос строки, очень часто это все ломает и приходится делать откат действия.

Записал короткое видео с примером
https://youtu.be/bGOiruga3i8

Подскажите пожалуйста как отключить такое поведение?

вот мой конфиг eslint

```json
{
  "plugins": ["functional", "import"],
  "extends": [
    "react-app",
    "plugin:prettier/recommended",
    "plugin:import/recommended",
    "plugin:import/typescript",
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended",
    "prettier/@typescript-eslint",
    "plugin:functional/external-recommended",
    "plugin:functional/recommended",
    "plugin:functional/stylitic"
  ],
  "settings": {
    "react": {
      "version": "detect"
    },
    "import/internal-regex": "^@(scenes|components|interfaces|constants|sprites|layouts|styles|utils|store)"
  },
  "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
  "parserOptions": {
    "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
    "ecmaFeatures": {
      "jsx": true
    }
  },
  "rules": {
    "semi": ["error", "always"],
    "no-console": [1, {
      "allow": ["warn", "error"]
    }],
    "@typescript-eslint/no-non-null-asserted-optional-chain": "off",
    "@typescript-eslint/no-non-null-assertion": "off",
    "@typescript-eslint/explicit-module-boundary-types": "off",
    "@typescript-eslint/no-var-requires": "off",
    "@typescript-eslint/explicit-function-return-type": [0],
    "@typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any": [0],
    "@typescript-eslint/no-empty-function": "off",
    "no-else-return": ["error", {
      "allowElseIf": false
    }],
    "import/no-unresolved": "off",
    "import/newline-after-import": ["error", {
      "count": 1
    }],
    "import/order": [
      "error",
      {
        "alphabetize": {
          "order": "asc",
          "caseInsensitive": true
        },
        "newlines-between": "always",
        "pathGroups": [{
          "pattern": "react",
          "group": "external",
          "position": "before"
        }],
        "pathGroupsExcludedImportTypes": ["react"],
        "groups": ["builtin", "external", "internal", "parent", "sibling", "index", "object"]
      }
    ],
    "functional/prefer-readonly-type": "off",
    "functional/no-expression-statement": "off",
    "functional/functional-parameters": "off",
    "functional/no-conditional-statement": "off",
    "functional/no-return-void": "off",
    "functional/immutable-data": "off",
    "functional/no-mixed-type": "off"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если в данное поведение не лезет расширение, то попробуйте сделать так

1. <kbd>F1</kbd>
2. В строку ввести: `Preferences: Open Settings (JSON)`
3. И в конец документа с настройками перед закрывающей фигурной скобкой добавить следующее

```json
"editor.formatOnPaste": false
```

4. Сохранить документ, потестить

Или через графический интерфейс:

1. File -> Preferences -> settings
2. В строку поиска вводите `editor format`
3. Снимаете галочку с `Format On Paste`
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Или можете данное поведение определить только для `typescript`. Как и в первом случае открываете json-файл с настройками и добавляете так

```json
    "[typescript]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "здесь ваш форматтер",
        "editor.formatOnPaste": false
    },
```

Comment: Помогло, спасибо большое

Comment: На здоровье, но с эмодзями у меня проблемы =)

Comment: @user447630 можете забирать более короткие ссылки, если нажмете `Поделиться` под ответом/вопросом